# Getting "has no 'x' member errors" for Rpi.GPIO using vscode remote ssh extension

Tags: python, ssh

I just set up my raspberry pi and have been using vscode (remote - ssh extension) on my windows computer to code on there but I have been getting errors like "Module 'RPi.GPIO' has no 'output' member". Autocomplete does work in vscode and everything runs well but there is a new error every time I use something from RPi.GPIO.

Is there anyway to fix this? or a way to hide these errors as everything does work so hiding would be fine.

Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

ledPin = 11

def setup():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
    GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.LOW)
    print('using pin%d'%ledPin)

def loop():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        print('led turned on >>>')
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.LOW)
        print('led turned off <<<')
        time.sleep(1)

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Program is starting... beep bop')
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()
```

Errors:
[image: Errors]

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and code please?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added that in!

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844378/pylint-no-member-issue-but-code-still-works-vscode ?